# How can I list external javascript resources being loaded by the page in casperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I suspect that not all scripts local to a target site are being loaded in my [casperJS](http://casperjs.org/) script. How can I confirm this i.e. how can I list the javascripts being loaded by the target page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the [resourceExists()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#resourceexists) function? From the documentation:

> Checks if a resource has been loaded. You can pass either a function, a string or a RegExp instance to perform the test

Or the [getGlobal](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getglobal) function if the script resources in question loads a global variable who's presence you could check for.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know the loaded scripts in xyz page with capserjs . you can do something like

```
scripts = casper.evaluate(function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('script')
});
```